# IECapt.exe not running on Windows Server 2012 Datacenter

Tags: php, iis, iecapt

I am facing a problem with IECapt.exe. I am using a PHP code to execute IECapt.exe to get the output and is not working on IIS. The code is running on Windows Server 2012 Datacenter. I am able to execute the same command on command prompt and able to get the output. Also, the same IEcapt.exe is successfully running on Windows Server 2008. Can somebody please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add rights for IIS-IUSRS user on the folder that IECapt.exe?

By the way I suggest checking Event Logs if you don't get any error messages.